# How to convert Row in partition

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario in spark.
Have to partition data frame.
resultant should be processed by each partition at a time.

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("con_dist_1", "con_dist_2", 
        "con_dist_3", "con_dist_4", "con_dist_5",
        "con_dist_6");
Dataset<Row> codes = sparkSession.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING());
Dataset<Row> partitioned_codes = codes.repartition(col("codes"));

// I need to paritition it dues to functional requirement
partitioned_codes.foreachPartition(itr -> {
    if (itr.hasNext()) {
        Row inrow = itr.next();
        System.out.println("inrow.length : " + inrow.length());
        System.out.println(inrow.toString());
        List<Object> objs = inrow.getList(0);
    }
});
```

**Getting error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getSeq(Row.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getSeq(rows.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getList(Row.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getList(rows.scala:166)
```

**Question :**
  How to handle `foreachPartition` here, where `itr` each iteration consists a group of Rows, how to get those rows using `itr`?

**Test 1:**

```
inrow.length: 0
[]
inrow.length: 0
[]
2020-03-02 05:22:14,179 [Executor task launch worker for task 615] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 110.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 615)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getString(Row.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getString(rows.scala:166)
```

**Output-1 :**

```
inrow.length: 0
[]
inrow.length: 0
[]
inrow.length: 1
[con_dist_1]
inrow.length: 1
[con_dist_2]
inrow.length: 1
[con_dist_5]
inrow.length: 1
[con_dist_6]
inrow.length: 1
[con_dist_4]
inrow.length: 1
[con_dist_3]
```

Comment: Are you just trying to convert `itr` to a list? `itr.next()` gives you the first value in the *next* record within the partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the rows of the partition are in `itr`. So when you call `itr.next()`, you only get the first row. If you need to print all the rows, you can use a `while` loop, or you can convert the iterator to a list with something like this (I suspect this is what you wanted to get to):

```
partitioned_codes.foreachPartition(itr -> {
    Iterable<Row> rowIt = () -> itr;
    List<String> objs = StreamSupport.stream(rowIt.spliterator(), false)
            .map(row -> row.getString(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("inrow.length: " + objs.size());
    System.out.println(objs);
});
```

The example code you posted didn't compile for me, so here's the version I tested with:

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("con_dist_1", "con_dist_2", 
        "con_dist_3", "con_dist_4", "con_dist_5",
        "con_dist_6");
StructType struct = new StructType()
        .add(DataTypes.createStructField("codes", DataTypes.StringType, true));
Dataset<Row> codes = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data, 2)
                        .map(s -> RowFactory.create(s)), struct);
Dataset<Row> partitioned_codes = codes.repartition(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("codes"));

partitioned_codes.foreachPartition(itr -> {
    Iterable<Row> rowIt = () -> itr;
    List<String> objs = StreamSupport.stream(rowIt.spliterator(), false)
            .map(row -> row.getString(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("inrow.length: " + objs.size());
    System.out.println(objs);
});
```

Comment: 1. I'm using `StreamSupport` just to stream over your iterator. One could also use a while loop and add values one by one to a `new ArrayList<String>` if desired. 2. You can of course, but that would have to be done like I did it in my full code. You should just not do it in the code for `forEachPartition`.

Comment: That is because there is no String there. Take care of what you put and what you get from the Row

Comment: @BdEngineer Can you maybe clarify what you're trying to achieve with the data in the partition? A `Row` will contain all your columns. And the code above pulls the one and only column from it, as I understand you were trying to do. Otherwise, maybe it's not a `DataSet<Row>` that you need. So please share what you're trying to achieve in the end...

Comment: `() -> itr` is just a lambda expression that makes an `Iterable<Row>` in this case.

Comment: Do you just need to convert the `Row`s from partitions to objects that you can process (like a custom class or a map/dictionary)? I'm struggling to understand the problem even after looking at your notebook.

Comment: No. With `() -> itr`, I create an `Iterable`, `itr` is an `Iterator`.